# Zend Tool & application.xml

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

I use NetBeans & Zend Tool (ZT). Then i create new project, ZT create a config file application.ini, but i need a xml version. I create a xml version of application.ini and update .zfproject.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<projectProfile type="default" version="1.10">
  <projectDirectory>
    <projectProfileFile filesystemName=".zfproject.xml"/>
    <applicationDirectory classNamePrefix="Application_">
      <apisDirectory enabled="false"/>
      <configsDirectory>
        <applicationConfigFile type="xml"/>
      </configsDirectory>
```

but this don't help me. Then i create new module, ZT create a application.ini. What need to do to ZT use application.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question a while ago, basically there's currently no way to do this.

See [How can I generate XML application configuration using Zend_Tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758393/how-can-i-generate-xml-application-configuration-using-zend-tool)